# Стиль Material Design не применяется к ToolBar

Tags: android, android-studio, xml

Необходимо установить стиль для toolbar: MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Surface

Цвет surface установлен #f6f6f6, даже сама студия это предъявляет, как на скриншоте: background: #f6f6f6

[image: Стиль]

Но в дизайне и на телефоне на ToolBar устанавливается PrimaryColor (#000000), который установлен в файле styles

[image: Скриншот приложения]

В коде проверил, нигде не устанавливается цвет для ToolBar. С этим получается бороться лишь явной установкой цвета background внутри тега. Что делать?

Код xml:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorlayout"
    android:background="#e5e5e5"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    >
    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarlayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >
        <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
            android:id="@+id/ToolBar_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.ActionBar.Surface"
            />
    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно использовать не ActionBar, а Toolbar

```
style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Toolbar.Surface"
```